# dompdf doesn't print correctly my custom font

Tags: fonts, drupal-7, dompdf, typekit

I'm having problems on printing the letters of my PDF with my custom font.
The script of my Typekit font is embed in my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/rhb5dhh.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="tk-museo" style="font-family:museo;">This is a test</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's suppoused to be ok, because I use the class "tk-museo", the one that have in it's css the font.

Some of the settings of the dompdf_config.inc.php are:

```
- def("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);
- def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_FONTSUBSETTING", false);
- def("DOMPDF_DEFAULT_FONT", "serif");
- def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP", true);
- def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT", true);
- def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);
- def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT", false);
- def("DOMPDF_AUTOLOAD_PREPEND", false);
- def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_HTML5PARSER", false);
```

Additional info:
- I've created a module that generate the PDF with drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

dompdf does not support JavaScript and so can not be used with TypeKit. You'll either need to find a font provider that uses CSS (@font) or allows you to download the fonts.

You only other option is to use a PDF rendering library that supports JavaScript (i.e. a headless browser). Something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org).

Comment: I've uploaded a font to dompdf using "load_font.php FontName /pathtofont.ttf" using a file.ttf and added inline the style to the <div> that contains the text. After doing that the pdf generate with the correct font but the letters didn't match the font for that letter

Comment: Which version of dompdf are you using? Can you post sample HTML and the resulting PDF?

Comment: hi BrianS, I'm using DOMPDF 0.6.0 beta 3, the HTML is exactly the same that I've posted above. The pdf only show a text just to test if the font is correctly displayed, right now the text is displayed with the default font "serif".

Comment: No errors when loading the font? Is the font represented in the font cache located at `dompdf/lib/fonts/dompdf_font_family_cache.php` (or .dist.php)?

Comment: hi BrianS, yes the font is represented in the dompdf_font_family_cache.php correctly

Comment: Does it work ok if you specify other fonts? What about the included Deja Vu fonts, e.g. Deja Vu Sans?

Comment: Hi BrianS, no it doesn't work with the included fonts like "dejavu sans", just print strange simbols.

Comment: What do you mean by strange symbols? If DejaVu Sans isn't working then the problem is more than just the fonts themselves. Could be that the file encoding doesn't match the encoding stated in the meta tag. Or perhaps the MBString library is missing.